# Equivalent projections in von Neumann algebras

Tags: c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be  a von Neumann algebra in $B(H)$. Let $p$ and $q$ 
be projections in $M$. Assume that they are equivalent in $B(H)$, i.e there is a partial isometry $u$ in $B(H)$ with $p=uu^*$ and $q=u^*u$.

Question: Are $p$ and $q$ equivalent in $M$?

Comment: No, let $H={\mathbb C}^2$ and $M\subset B(H)\cong M_2({\mathbb C})$ be the diagonal matrices. Then let $p$ and $q$ be the projections to the first and second coordinate.

Comment: Yes, that shows that they are equivalent in $B(H)$. But as $M$ is abelian, they are not equivalent in $M$.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should have been thought through more carefully

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to your question is negative.
Take two inequivalent projections in a type $II_1$ factor $R\subset B(H)$.
These projections have infinite dimensional range in $H$.
They are therefore equivalent in $B(H)$.